# Convert IP's in Numeric to traditional IP display

Tags: sql, sql-server, ip

I am trying to convert IP addresses from numeric (eg 4183726815 ) to the actual traditional IP display (eg 192.168.1.230) in MS SQL Server.

I have found other code (below), however I then get an error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IntegerToIPAddress (@IP AS bigint)

RETURNS varchar(15)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Octet1 tinyint

DECLARE @Octet2 tinyint

DECLARE @Octet3 tinyint

DECLARE @Octet4 tinyint

DECLARE @RestOfIP bigint

SET @Octet1 = @IP / 16777216

SET @RestOfIP = @IP - (@Octet1 * 16777216)

SET @Octet2 = @RestOfIP / 65536

SET @RestOfIP = @RestOfIP - (@Octet2 * 65536)

SET @Octet3 = @RestOfIP / 256

SET @Octet4 = @RestOfIP - (@Octet3 * 256)

RETURN(CONVERT(varchar, @Octet1) + '.' +

CONVERT(varchar, @Octet2) + '.' +

CONVERT(varchar, @Octet3) + '.' +

CONVERT(varchar, @Octet4))

END
```

And when I run

```
SELECT dbo.IntegerToIPAddress(2130806436)
```

It returns 127.1.134.164. Which is exactly what is required.

However, when I run my data ip's , I get the following error:
eg

```
SELECT dbo.IntegerToIPAddress2(3232235780)
```

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Any ideas? Or should I try another approach from the above code?

Thanks folks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variable declaration from `Tinyint` to `Bigint` as:

```
DECLARE @Octet1 bigint

DECLARE @Octet2 bigint

DECLARE @Octet3 bigint

DECLARE @Octet4 bigint
```

Comment: Hi there Deepshikha, that did the trick! Thanks so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The line: 
    SET @RestOfIP = @IP - (@Octet1 * 16777216)

Is treating the constant 16777216 as an int and then expecting the multiplication result to be int.  You need to tell it that it will be bigint.

```
SET @RestOfIP = @IP - (@Octet1 * CONVERT(bigint, 16777216))
```

Comment: Hi bitflipper, I tried your suggestion as well as Deepshika's, and both work well. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Deepshikha s answer is probably the more correct one since it removes the implicit conversions that my answer was looking to specifically highlight.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has INET_NTOA and INET_ATON built in functions;
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton
Google search revealed that MS SQL has those as well.
Hope this helps someone looking for an answer now.